# Android project build failed on project creation

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

When I first build project in Android Studio 3.0.1 I always have build failed

[image: error trace]

I know the solution for that particular error when I need to change "compileSdkVersion" to 28 and few others issues like add word "Base" before "Theme" to be UI elements visible.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

My build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.dodge.timerapp"
        minSdkVersion 28
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

But, that error start occuring week before, till that time everything was fine.

Comment: It is crazy to have minSdkVersion (28) > targetSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion (26)

Comment: Invalidate cache and restart.

Answer (score 0):

minSdkVersion <= targetSdkVersion <= compileSdkVersion
midsdkversion must be less make 19 or 21

Answer (score 0):

1-) Try checking your internet connection , gradle download dependencies from servers whenever a new project is created.

2-) If internet connection is good then try invalidating cache and restart Android Studio `File => Invalidate caches/Restart => click on invalidate caches and restart`

3-) If first and second steps don't help try , from Android Studio toolbar select
`Build => Clean Project => Rebuild project` by going in build menu again

4-) You might want to check your antivirus software setting and your computer's firewall rules to see that they are not affecting Android Studio project build.

5-) If you see that Android Studio is not allowed through firewall , click on allow an app through firewall and mark the checkbox saying android studio and click on apply and try again.

For antivirus check the android developers website documentation for locations to be excluded from security scan on
https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#optimize-studio-windows